# Infrequent but exactly timed 15 minute silent crash in Windows 7 64bit process

Tags: windows-7, crash

I'm experiencing a crash in iRacing (simulation racing video game) and it is occurring at exactly 15 minutes after the process starts (I've stopwatched many times). The crash doesn't always happen (some sessions go hours and exit normally). Getting beyond 15 minutes seems to always be stable but doesn't mean future sessions will be stable. The crash is instantaneous to the desktop, there are no error dialogs, and no error logs from iRacing, and no Windows Event Viewer errors/warnings.

After much, much testing (1.5months+), I'm lead to believe some 15 minute schedule or process or service or job or piece of logic in windows or something is kicking in and hard killing the iRacing process.

So, what could cause such a 15 minute crash?

No other apps or games exhibit this crash that I'm aware of. I've tested memory (more than a few multi-hour sessions up to 18 hours each), temperatures well within limits, no other crashes to make me suspect power supply, motherboard, hard drives, etc.

Many of us have been testing the problem and reporting on the iRacing forums for about 2 months now with no success.

This is why I'm lead to believe that, while it may be triggered by recent iRacing updates, it's something about Windows, or drivers, or services that is causing the problem.

I'm asking on SuperUser because I feel this is a question for tech people not video game people.

Here are my system specs if it helps: Intel Core i7 2600K @ 3.40GHz / ASUS P8Z68-V / 16GB MEM / 240GB SSD / Gigabyte G1 Gaming NVIDIA GTX 980 Ti 6GB / 3x Benq GL2760 NVIDIA Surround / SimXperience AccuForce Pro / Logitech G27 Pedals and Shifter / Obutto R3volution / Logitech Z906 5.1 Surround Sound / Windows 7 Home

Thank you,

Comment: Could be that the game has a "phone home" function that simply exits if it cannot connect to their servers...

Comment: We've been in touch with iRacing who say they don't have any 15min functionality like that.

Comment: Not a solution but: We discovered that powering on our steering wheels only after the game fully launched to its main screen allowed the game to remain stable. It sounds like a timeout issue on their side of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, another iRacing user discovered that if he got into an iRacing session *before* powering on his wheel it was stable 100% of the time.

Later updates to iRacing fixed this and you can power on your wheel before starting iRacing and this is now stable 100% of the time from my experience since I reported this issue.